# Xtext issue with Code Completion

Tags: xtext

**Based on the following Xtext (2.10) code snippet:**
[image]

**The expectation for "CRT+L":**

[image]

**The ISSUE:**

**If "CRT+L" is done on the "BEGSR" token, the "Name - ID" option is missing.**
[image]

**When Enter is pressed and incorrect token "BEGSR*PSSR" is created. The rule should be that "BEGSR" is always followed by a space. BUT IT IS NOT!**

[image]

Please help me,

1. Auto add space after "BEGSR"
2. Have "Name - ID" option available when "CRL+L" on "BEGSR" token
3. Have "ENDSR" auto added like "{}" and "()" brackets

Answer (score 1):

Xtext has two extension points for such things

- there is the proposal provider that lets you adapt the existing proposals. It has methods for completion places like `complete_<Rulename>` or `complete<Rulename>_<featurename>` and some special rules like `completeKeyword` that you may override and customize.
- auto insert on typing is called auto edit strategy and implemented by `DefaultAutoEditStrategy`